# How do I read a simple touch sensor value from Arduino?

Tags: arduino, sensor, touch

I suppose instead of  connecting to the LED it will connect to A3 on the Arduino for example but I'm  having a hard time making it work.
[image]
I don't know which point on the circuit should be connected to which pin on the Arduino. I seem to get values alternating between 950 and 1050.

**My question is in general how this should be connected to the Arduino.**

Comment: Touch sensor specs?

Comment: 9 V into an Arduino ---> Unhappy ending.

Comment: @Transistor That's why my question says - generally. Please don't look at the specs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of "don't look at the specs"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, be cautious not to connect the two touch terminals together, it may damage the transistor.

The circuit can be manipulated in various ways to sense for a finger touch at the touch terminal. One of the ways can be to take a wire from the collector of the transistor and give it to the Arduino(make sure to use a lower voltage battery). When the transistor is off(no touch), the voltage at collector terminal should be at a higher voltage level and when transistor is on(touched), the voltage should be at a lower voltage level.

You can check for the typical values that occur at some of the points in the circuit using a multimeter and decide how you can use these points to give input to the microcontroller.